# When adding a related row through a FactBox more... link, the new row is not linked to the parent. Bug or am I missing something?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm working through the Veterinary example (see below) for Dynamics AX 2012 and have created a FactBox that shows all the pets of the currently selected customer. I've previously added a form that allows new pets to be added and linked that form to a new button on the ribbon bar.

When I open that form through the ribbon bar adding a new pet works. When I click the "more..." link in the FactBox the same form is displayed but adding a new pet then, fails to link the pet to the customer.

Is this a bug/shortcoming in AX? Or am I missing something?

EDIT: The example consists of creating 3 tables: Species (SpeciesID, Name), Breed (BreedId, SpeciesId, Name) and Pet (CustomerAccount, SpeciesID, BreedId, Gender, Name). Then producing forms to edit those three tables and finally linking everything to the customer form (accounts payable)

Comment: You'll need to be more specific when referring to the veterinary example.

Comment: @AlexKwitny done

Comment: I think we need to see the example instructions or some code or something. If it's a stand-alone example, maybe PasteBin the XPO or something. You're just describing the task but seeing the code helps to solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexKwitny Here's the PasteBin https://pastebin.com/DhAfNwne I had to remove some of existing items. Hopefully I haven't mangled the file too much...

Comment: @AlexKwitny I think this is the veterinary example that is used throughout the labs of the Development I-III training material.

Comment: @FH-Inway Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Data source is specified on the New menubutton

Comment: I have. And the menubutton is not the problem. When adding a new related entry via the "more..." button in the factbox, this is when I get the issue